# CS50 Tideman Prints winner of election when some pairs are tied

Tags: c, cs50

I got the code to work and passed the test. My question is why initializing int counter outside the for loop failed to pass the "prints winner of election when some pairs are tied" check, but initializing int counter inside the outer for loop passed the check. I tried Googling and someone said declaring the int inside the for loop provides the smallest scope. I'm not sure how this works. Thank you!

```
// Print the winner of the election
void print_winner(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            if (locked[j][i] == false)
            {
                counter++;
                if (counter == candidate_count)
                {
                    printf("%s\n", candidates[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: The code above will print a candidate's name when their complete column in the array is set to `false`. (The test `if (counter == candidate_count)` need not be inside the loop, because it can't reach the row count until the loop is complete.) But if you move `int counter = 0;` to the top, then the message will be printed when there are `candidate_count` of `false` values found *somewhere* in the whole array, and then the name of the particular candidate where it reached the required count isn't relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring a variable with `int` resets it's value.

Here's an example of code that demonstrates the difference. It's a little program that takes a list of list of numbers, and prints out how many times each sub-list has a 3.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int data[5][4] = {
    { 1, 5, 3, 4 }, // 1 3
    { 2, 3, 3, 2 }, // 2 3s
    { 3, 3, 3, 9 }, // 3 3s
    { 3, 3, 2, 8 }, // 2 3s
    { 0, 5, 1, 4 }, // 0 3s
};

// Prints out the number of 3s in each row of the array
void count_threes_v0(void) {
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<4; j++) {
            if (data[i][j] == 3) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        printf("Row %d has %d 3s\n", i, counter);
    }
}

void count_threes_v1(void) {
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        int counter = 0;
        for (int j=0; j<4; j++) {
            if (data[i][j] == 3) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        printf("Row %d has %d 3s\n", i, counter);
    }
}
```

In the example above, `v0` prints out this:

```
Row 0 has 1 3s
Row 1 has 3 3s
Row 2 has 6 3s
Row 3 has 8 3s
Row 4 has 8 3s
```

and `v1` prints out this:

```
Row 0 has 1 3s
Row 1 has 2 3s
Row 2 has 3 3s
Row 3 has 2 3s
Row 4 has 0 3s
```

You can see that v1 is correct, and v0 is not.

When you write `int counter = 0` inside the first for loop, it means that counter gets reset each time the loop rolls around. When it's outside the loop, the values carry over.

The bug in v0 is that the counter never resets, which is also the issue in your code.